# where is this empty space coming from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I didn't write the form but the css is only 8 lines + bootstraps form control and then some classes for the javascript but I cannot figure out why the place holder text bit, or actually it's parent div, is becoming 60px or so in height, there is only 15px padding top and bottom and then a margin for the placeholder text. I've gone through form-control and there's no styles for height so I just can't figure it out. If you could have a look that'd be great.

http://danceforovariancancer.com.au#perform

Here's the contact form html and it's css but I'd recomend inspecting element because there's no answers in the css as far as I can tell :o

```
<section id="perform">
<div class="container-fluid apply">
   <div class="text-center row">
      <h1>Want to perform? Sign up here</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
         <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
               <div class="row control-group">
                  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                     <label>Name</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                     <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row control-group">
                  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                     <label>Email</label>
                     <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                     <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row control-group">
                  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                     <label>Phone</label>
                     <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                     <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
               <div class="row control-group">
                  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                     <label>Message</label>
                     <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                     <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="success"></div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.apply {
    background-color: #0094ab;
}
.form-control {
    color: #fff !important;
}
.floating-label-form-group {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    /*     padding-bottom: .5em; */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;/*     color: #0094ab; */
}
.floating-label-form-group input,  .floating-label-form-group textarea {
    z-index: 1;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24);
    box-shadow: none!important;
    resize: none;
}
.floating-label-form-group label {
    display: block;
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 2em;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: .85em;
    line-height: 1.764705882em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: top .3s ease, opacity .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: top .3s ease, opacity .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: top .3s ease, opacity .3s ease;
    transition: top .3s ease, opacity .3s ease;/*     color: #fff; */
}
.floating-label-form-group-with-value label {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
.floating-label-form-group-with-focus label {
    color: #80bc18;
}
form .row:first-child .floating-label-form-group {
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}
 .form-control::-moz-placeholder {
 color: #999;
 opacity: 1;
}
 .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
 color: #999;
}
 .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: #999;
/*   font-size: 12px; */
}
```

Comment: Looks like there's hidden label above the input, with `opacity` set to 0 and `z-index` set to 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have hidden labels (`opacity:0`) which takes the space. Actually `Opacity:0` hides the element (here: the labels), but reserves the space. You can use `display:none` instead, to completely hide an element. 
I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you man, I had actually given up on getting the floating labels to work but once I realised they were actually there but just hidden I went back to some other js files and found a random ass section where the guy had put the java script for a class change with top position changes. So thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

As others have said the problem is caused by the hidden label.
If you're looking for a quick fix, here's what I would do:

In your **mystyles.css** add top margin for .form-control.

```
.form-control {
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply following changes

```
label {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  top:0 !important;
}
.floating-label-form-group input, .floating-label-form-group textarea {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 0;
  position: relative;
  resize: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
.form-control {
  color: #fff !important;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

[image]